# #1064 - an error in SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '<!doctype html>

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

i tried to import database into my cpanel, but i get this error :

```
   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '<!doctype html>
<html lang="id" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  ...' at line 1
```

https://www.rumahweb.com/journal/cara-upload-wordpress-dari-localhost-ke-hosting/

i follow step by step from this link to exporting database from localhost and importing it into cpanel, but still got the error.

and when i open the sql file that i've export from localhost DB, it contain html tags like this :

[image: this is sql file that i export from localhost DB]

Comment: That's not SQL. That's HTML. It seems you haven't correctly exported your database. You should retry exporting. If you can't get proper SQL, then describe exactly the steps you're performing (don't just link to tutorial) and provide the entire text of the resulting HTML/SQL that gets exported (as text, not an image)

Comment: It seems to me that you should find a SQL book or tutorial, so that you at ;east know what SQL looks like before you begin working with a database. Clearly what you have posted in the image as your *SQL file* is not SQL, but is HTML instead (which is also made clear by the `<doctype html>` at the beginning).

Comment: refer this site. it will help you https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-backup-restore-a-mysql-database